# React redirects to wrong route on page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, routes, redux-toolkit

I am using React and Redux toolkit for frontend and I have implemented jwt authentication with user roles.

The application has a sidebar which contains two pages (profile, lottery) for employee and (admin lottery) for admin user only.

The problem is that I can only access the lottery page or admin lottery when i click on sidebar button that redirects to the desired page, otherwise react always redirect back to profile page, even if i write the lottery page url on browser, it will also redirects to profile page.

Also if I am on lottery page and I refresh the page, it will redirect back to profile page, and this is wrong, it should return to the lottery page instead.

This behaviour happens when i added the authentication feature, but I didn't know which line of code causes this issue.

If anyone could help me, it will be highly appreciated.

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
  const authData = useSelector((store) => store.authReducer)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          {/* Authentication */}
          <Route path="/" element={<FullScreenlayout />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/connecter" replace />} />
            <Route
              path="connecter"
              element={
                authData.isAuthenticated ? (
                  <Navigate to="/employee/profil" replace />
                ) : (
                  <Login />
                )
              }
            />
          </Route>

          {/* Employee space */}
          <Route path="/employee/" element={<MainLayout />}>
            <Route
              path="/employee/"
              element={<Navigate to="/employee/profil" replace />}
            />

            {/* Allow for all employees */}
            <Route
              path="profil"
              element={
                <ProtectedRoute
                  element={<Profile />}
                  isAllowed={true}
                  link={"/connecter"}
                  isAuthenticated={authData.isAuthenticated}
                />
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="tirage"
              element={
                <ProtectedRoute
                  element={<Lottery />}
                  isAllowed={true}
                  link={"/connecter"}
                  isAuthenticated={authData.isAuthenticated}
                />
              }
            />
          </Route>

          {/* Admin space */}
          <Route path="/admin/" element={<MainLayout />}>
            {/* Allow only for lottery admin */}
            <Route
              path="tirage"
              element={
                <ProtectedRoute
                  element={<AdminLottery />}
                  isAllowed={authData.currentUser.role?.includes(
                    CONSTANTS.roles.lottery
                  )}
                  link={"/employee/profil"}
                  isAuthenticated={authData.isAuthenticated}
                />
              }
            />
          </Route>

          {/* Not found url path */}
          <Route
            path="*"
            element={
              <ProtectedRoute
                element={<Navigate to="/employee/profil" replace />}
                isAllowed={true}
                link={"/connecter"}
                isAuthenticated={authData.isAuthenticated}
              />
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

**ProtectedRoute.js**

```
const ProtectedRoute = (props) => {
    if (props.isAllowed && props.isAuthenticated) {
        return props.element
    } else {
        return <Navigate to={props.link} replace />
    }
  
}

export default ProtectedRoute
```

[Please see this video to get an idea about the problem.](https://mega.nz/file/CdB0WY5a#fRVhVxZ16z6qGJFtic8SjwWrL61kZCZF1A9uSLt7DcY)

Comment: Is authData exited in local storage, or do you make an API call to fetch it on every page refresh (F5) and then save it to the store? You can console.log(props) in ProtectedRoute to see that value of "isAllowed" and "isAuthenticated". I think it will be false at the first time. And then you call api to update it in store to true, that why you can navigate to admin after that

Comment: @Tony No it is not stored in localstorage. I added a function in react useEffect in app.js that always checks if access token is still in localstorage then change isAuthenticated to True else to False, and exactly as you said when refreshing the page (F5) it will log isAuthenticated is false the first time, then it returns isAuthenticated True. Should I store isAuthenticated in localStorage.

Comment: I think the problem is you pass prop from App to ProtectedRoute. The 1st time (when you f5) it will be false, even later the prop authData have updated to true. It has already navigated to other page and not re-run the logic in ProtectedRoute any more. Can you move const authData = useSelector((store) => store.authReducer) inside ProtectedRoute

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the navigate to "/employee/profil" route in the Employee Space Route.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'isExact' property on the first route in Authentication "path='/'".

Answer (score 0):

wrap ur App component with the BrowserRouter in the index.js

```js
  <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
```

and that still wont fix the problem